# How to get the record with the same values except primary key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql

Suppose the records in database are as below:

```
Id         FirstName       LastName        OrderPrice
1          Tom             Hanks           123
2          Tom             Hanks           173
3          Tom             Hanks           123
4          Tom             Bob             123
5          Robert          Hanks           123

Given Input : Id = 1
Expected OUtput : Id = 3
```

I know that I can write some thing like below

```
Declare @Id as INT = 1
Declare @FirstName as varchar(100)
Declare @LastName as varchar(100)
Declare @OrderPrice as INT

Select @FirstName = FirstName, @LastName  = LastName , @OrderPrice = OrderPrice  From Customers Where Id= @ID

Select ID From Customers Where FirstName = @FirstName and LastName = @LastName and OrderPrice = @OrderPrice
```

But, I do not want to write some thing like where I should mention all the columns names in where condition. Because actually the record I was working on contains almost 100 columns in it. So, I was asked not to use a query some thing like this.

Can any one help me how to do this?

Comment: I think your database is set up wrong. You should have a linked table with the names, rather than repeating them. Then start with that table, and find the orders for a customer.   If you don't have a say in the database structure, it is already set, this advice doesn't help much.

Comment: This is a fine argument for natural keys :)

Comment: At any rate, what should be returned if there is more than one duplicate?  All but the record that you are using as the input to the query?  Only the first duplicate record?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName, OrderPrice) AS Cnt, * FROM Customers) Res WHERE Res.Cnt > 1` But you still have to name at least once the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL to create a query to search for duplicate records.  Basically, this query builds a string like `a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and ...` and uses that as the `on` clause in a self-join:

```
declare @columns varchar(max)

select  @columns = 
            case when @columns is null then 'a.' else @columns + ' and a.' end +
            quotename(name) + ' = b.' + quotename(name)
from    sys.columns
where   object_id = object_id('YourTable')
        and name <> 'ID'

declare @query varchar(max)
set @query = 'select b.ID from YourTable a ' +
    'join YourTable b on a.ID <> b.ID and ' + @columns + ' where a.ID = 1'
exec (@query)
```

This searches for rows that duplicate `ID = 1`, except for the ID.

Comment: I think, space is missing before `and a.` (in the CASE expression).

Comment: @Andriy M: Edited! but it still worked because `quotename` returns a string like `a.[col1] = b.[col1]and a.[col2] ...` which seems to be valid t-sql

Comment: Indeed! I didn't think about that. Of course, the closing bracket serves as a word delimiter here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Id as INT = 1

WITH
    dupes AS
    (
        SELECT
C1.Id,
            C1.FirstName,
            C1.LastName,
            C1.OrderPrice
        FROM
            Customers C1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers C2
        ON
            C1.FirstName = C2.FirstName
        AND C1.LastName = C2.LastName
        AND C1.OrderPrice = C2.OrderPrice
        WHERE
            C1.Id <> C2.Id
    )
SELECT
    dupes.Id
FROM
    Customer
INNER JOIN dupes
ON
    Customer.FirstName = dupes.FirstName
AND Customer.LastName = dupes.LastName
AND Customer.OrderPrice = dupes.OrderPrice
WHERE
   Customer.Id = @Id
AND dupes.Id <> @Id
```